# I can't use .htaccess and .htpasswd to lock folders in FTP

Tags: php, .htaccess, ftp

I have two folders I want to lock, I put both .htaccess and .htpasswd in the folder I want to lock and when I enter my index.php (which is not located in the "locked" folder) I still have to login there even though I didn't want to lock that folder I just wanted to lock the other one where I put my .htaccess and .htpasswd. Why does this lock my index page when I put .htaccess and .htpasswd in the other folder which is /home/username/php/HERE. I can also add that I do not have any other .htaccess on my site.

Comment: apache is a server (can be configured via .htaccess) ftp is a server (.htaccess is just a file) => answer NO. For FTP you need to defined user rights ...

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. It depends on your host and type of server as to how they/you have set up how the web server handles them. Normally .htaccess and .htpasswd will lock the whole site.

I have found the following:
This may help you!
http://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess

Comment: yeah I have checked that and I did everything. I have mailed my host to see if I have the rights to use htaccess and htpasswd. I hope they answer soon.

Comment: Ahh okay, well normally I don't use them to do things like that. If you can't figure something out, give me an email: danny.smc95@gmail.com and I shall try to help!